# Facebook Feed Dialog does not open

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building a custom multi friend selector in order to send posts to friend's walls on Facebook based on this tutorial
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/

I have been able to load my list of friends and create a CSV list of people I want to post to but the last step of opening the feed dialog is failing and I don't understand why. The dialog does not open.

this is my sendRequest function

```
    var sendUIDs = '';
   $('.cbFriendId').each(function(index){
        if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
        var addId = $(this).attr('value');
        sendUIDs += addId + ',';
        }
    });
    console.log(sendUIDs);
    openSendDialog(sendUIDs);
    }


   function openSendDialog(sendUIDs){
   console.log('open send dialog');
   FB.ui({
       method: 'feed',
       to: sendUIDs,
       link: 'http://www.mydomain.com',
       display: 'iframe',
       message: 'Hello from My Domain',
       name: 'Click to view my app',
       caption: 'Hello my app'

   },
               function (response) {
                   if (response) {
                       alert('Post was published.');
                       console.log('Post was published.');
                   } else {
                       alert('Post was not published.');
                       console.log('Post was not published.');
                   }
               }
             );
 }
```

The last console log entry is 'open send dialog'. I get no errors in IE9 dev tools but I do get an 'Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame ...' error in chrome.

just for sanity sake here is my graph init

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '462750593765445', // App ID
        channelUrl: '//www.mydomain.com/channel.html', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
        frictionlessRequests: false 
    });
};
```

Also I should mention that the app is in sandbox mode.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I should mention that I am able to get the pop up for app authentication and permissions to fire.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called `Send Dialog`, So you need to change your method from `feed` to `send` and it should work.

Check out their docs for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/